# How to select path from nested sets excluding subtrees

Tags: sql, sqlite, nested

I have an SQLite database, which contains trees with red and black nodes (not red-black trees though). Trees are stored as nested sets (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nested_set_model)

```
Name TreeId Left Right IsBlack
A    1      1    8     1
B    1      2    7     0
C    1      3    6     1
D    1      4    5     1
A    2      1    10    1
B    2      2    5     0
C    2      6    9     1
D    2      3    4     1
D    2      7    8     1
```

Both B and C nodes with TreeId = 2 point to D node. So D is written twice.

These trees may contain only black or only red nodes

I would like to select all paths for the specified node, that do not contain red nodes, i. e. exclude red nodes and all their subtrees from result

Examples:

For record:

```
Name TreeId Left Right IsBlack
A    1      1    8     1
```

the result will be:

```
Name TreeId Left Right IsBlack
A    1      1    8     1
```

For record:

```
Name TreeId Left Right IsBlack
C    1      3    6     1
```

the result will be:

```
Name TreeId Left Right IsBlack
C    1      3    6     1
D    1      4    5     1
```

And, finally, for record:

```
Name TreeId Left Right IsBlack
A    2      1    10    1
```

The result will be:

```
Name TreeId Left Right IsBlack
A    2      1    10    1
C    2      6    9     1
D    2      7    8     1
```

To keep it simple, let's assume that there is another query, which selects TreeId, Left and Right parameters of the searched node by its name.

So I came up with the following query (for node A):

```
SELECT Nodes.* FROM Nodes
LEFT JOIN Nodes as n ON Nodes.[TreeId] = n.TreeId AND n.IsBlack = 0 AND Nodes.Left >= n.Left AND Nodes.Right <= n.Right
AND n.Left >= 1 AND n.Right <= 10
WHERE Nodes.TreeId = 2 AND Nodes.Left >= 1 AND Nodes.[Right] <= 10 AND n.Name IS NULL
```

The query seems to work, but it's terribly slow because of left join even with indexes.

So I was wondering, is there a way to optimize the query in terms of SQLite avoiding left join (for example using inner joins, unions, etc)

P.S. I cannot change the way the data is stored, but I can modify database schema (add new fields).

P.P.S. I understand, that I can query all results, and then filter them on the code side. The other option is to store two types of trees in db: one with red and black nodes, and the other one with black nodes only. However, both of these solutions are last resorts.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you clarify what the TreeID, Left and Right columns do? For representing a tree structure in a table, I'm used to the id being unique, and the left and right columns referring to the ids of that record's children, but that doesn't seem to be the case here.

Comment: TreeId is required if multiple trees stored in the database. In my example there are 2 trees (with TreeId 1 and 2 accordingly). Left and Right are used to store trees as nested sets (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nested_set_model)

Answer (score 1):

Okay, I don't know if it'll be faster or not - can't tell with only a few rows of data, but this one uses a recursive CTE to at least get the same results as your examples:

```sql
WITH RECURSIVE n AS
 (SELECT * FROM nodes WHERE name= ?1 AND treeid = ?2 AND isblack = 1
  UNION ALL
  SELECT n2.name, n2.treeid, n2.left, n2.right, n2.isblack
   FROM n
   JOIN nodes AS n2  
   ON     n2.treeid = n.treeid
      AND (n2.left = n.left + 1 OR n2.right = n.right - 1)
   WHERE n2.isblack = 1)
SELECT * FROM n ORDER BY name
```

You'll probably want an index on `nodes(isblack, treeid, name)` (And don't forget to run a [PRAGMA optimize](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_analyze.html) once in a while.) Bind/replace `?1` and `?2` with the obvious values for a particular run of the query.

Comment: Thanks, Shawn. Didn't know that sqlite supports cte. Will check your answer and reply with the results

Comment: Ok, finally tested it out. The cte query took about 3 seconds to execute on a 100K+ nodes. As I understand cte is expanded in a set of subqueries, which is pretty slow. Left join is faster in my case, however it is also too slow. What I finally ended up with is to create a new field Lastknownredparent and store the left node id in each red node and all its children and 0 if the node is black and has no red parents. Thus, adding Lastknownredparent < leftid in where clause, where leftid is the left field of the searched node gives me the desired result, without using left join or cte